# Multiple where conditions with IN using Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to use below query in hibernate.

```
Select * from Employee where (Name= 'XXXX' and age = 30) OR (Name = 'YYYY' or age = 40);
```

I may get multiple names and age at run-time. It is not definite in count.

I tried doing following:

```
Select * from Employee where Name in ('XXXX','YYYYY') AND age in (30,40);
```

And obviously gave wrong result.

Answer (score 0):

Try formatting it like this.

```
SELECT
FROM
WHERE
AND
```

Instead of how you're doing it so that you can say

```
SELECT name, age
FROM Employee
WHERE name='xxxx' AND age='30' OR (name = 'yyyy' OR age = 40);
```

Comment: If if is 2 value then fine. If i get 1000 values in runtime how can i format ?

Answer (score 0):

Good question! There is simple solution:

```
    String hql = "from AEmployee where Name||age in (:ids)";
    List<Employee>list=entityManager.createQuery(hql).setParameter("ids", 
        new   LinkedList<String>() {
        {
            add("XXXX30");
            add("YYYY40");
        }
    }).getResultList();
```

The query with field concatenation is not optimal for big table, you will need to create functional index on this table, or create service field with result of concatenation, and index it.

Answer (score 0):

you can write like this..

```
   Select emp from Employee emp where emp.name in ('XXXX','YYYYY') and emp.age in (30,40)
```